# Issue with a function receiving variables from another function that updates on input

Tags: javascript, function, dom

http://jsfiddle.net/sSwvq/94/

title says most of it, I'm having an issue with the very last function, it's receiving variables from function b, and function b received variables from function a, and function a works based on whenever a user changes their input.

The way the data is sent is

input.functionA sends variable 1 and runs function b

input.functionA sends variable 2 and runs function b

input.functionA sends variable 3 and runs function b

functionB(1) sends variable 4 and runs function c

functionB(2) sends variable 5 and runs function c

functionB(3) sends variable 6 and runs function c

functionC(4,5,6) receives one variable at a time(which I think is the issue, as its run without collecting all of the variables) and runs the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Code is below!
HTML

```
<form>
<input id="wineQty" class="qty" type="text" placeholder="Wine Tasting Amount" />
<input id="dinnerQty" class="qty" type="text" placeholder="Dinner Amount" />
<input id="golfTeamQty" class="qty" type="text" placeholder="Golf Team Amount" />
</form>

<!--display total cost here--> 
The Costs are: <br>
Wine Tasting: <span id="wineCostTag"> </span> <br>
Dinner: <span id="dinnerCostTag"> </span> <br>
Golf Team: <span id="golfCostTag"> </span> <br>
Total Cost: <span id="orderTotalCost"> </span>
```

Javascript

```
var wineCost = 20;
var wineQuantity = document.getElementById("wineQty");

var dinnerCost = 30;
var dinnerQuantity = document.getElementById("dinnerQty");

var golfTeamCost = 400;
var golfTeamQuantity = document.getElementById("golfTeamQty");

var wineCostTag = document.getElementById("wineCostTag");
var dinnerCostTag = document.getElementById("dinnerCostTag");
var golfCostTag = document.getElementById("golfCostTag");
var orderTotalCost = document.getElementById("orderTotalCost");

wineQuantity.oninput =  function(){
    var val1 = parseInt(wineQuantity.value, 10);
    updateWine(val1);
};

dinnerQuantity.oninput =  function(){
    var val2 = parseInt(dinnerQuantity.value, 10);
    updateDinner(val2);
};

golfTeamQuantity.oninput =  function(){
    var val3 = parseInt(golfTeamQuantity.value, 10);
    updateGolf(val3);
};

function updateWine(val1) {
    var wineTotalCost = (wineCost * val1);
    wineCostTag.innerHTML = wineTotalCost;
    updateTotal(wineTotalCost);
}

function updateDinner(val2) {
    var dinnerTotalCost = (30 * val2);
    dinnerCostTag.innerHTML = dinnerTotalCost;
    updateTotal(dinnerTotalCost);
}

function updateGolf(val3) {
    var golfTeamTotalCost = (400 * val3);
    golfCostTag.innerHTML = golfTeamTotalCost;
    updateTotal(golfTeamTotalCost);
}


function updateTotal(wineTotalCost, dinnerTotalCost, golfTeamTotalCost) {
    var totalCost = (wineTotalCost + dinnerTotalCost + golfTeamTotalCost);
    orderTotalCost.innerHTML = totalCost
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch in arguments, you can't just add arguments and expect them to magically work, you have to actually call the function with those arguments, but in your case you should get the values directly in the updateTotal function instead.

Comment: so along with sending them to updateWine/updateDinner/updateGolf I should send them from the oninput to one big function at the end?

Edit: Or just do the updateWine/dinner/golf in the oninput itself and send out the individual totals from the oninput to a larger function

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sSwvq/97/

Comment: Are you a wizard adeneo? Haha that's perfect. Why is it that you had to call the CostTags and etc again? In the final function is it pulling from what it already updated into the html?(So like the individual functions --> HTML --->total function -->HTML? I'm new to the DOM stuff.

Comment: Including variable names in a parameter list (e.g. `val3` in `function updateGolf(val3)`) is effectively the same as declaring them in the function body. Values are passed by their position in the call and matched by position to names in the parameter list, not by name.

Comment: @Soccham You seem to have a serious misunderstanding about how function calling works, which is basic to practically all programming. I think you need to hit the books and learn the fundamentals.

Comment: You don't need the arguments, as you can't really send all the arguments from three different event handlers at the same time anyway. I see now that I forgot to remove them in the fiddle, so it's possibly a little confusing, but this is more accurate -> http://jsfiddle.net/sSwvq/102/

Comment: I saw that, I also removed them from where the oninput functions call the updateTotal(). I feel like I understand it now, thank you for your help!